# Return only directory from Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

The following query searched for locations of a file in PowerShell. Is there any way to just return the directory instead of the directory attributes and filename?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\random\random -Filter nameofile -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want the names of the directories that contain matched files here:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\random\random -Filter nameofile -Recurse | % { split-path $_.fullname } | sort -uniq
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\random\random -Filter nameofile -Recurse).DirectoryName
```

Comment: PSv2 alternative: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\random\random -Filter nameofile -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique`